# nodejs library for google adwords api

Tags: node.js, soap, google-ads-api

I want to use Google Adwords API, I'm a node js developer, but I can't find a library for it (I did find this unofficial one `node-adwords` but it not well documented and there is no examples -_-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move to the Google Ads API? It's also got an unofficial node library, but it's much better documented (and doesn't use SOAP, yuck): https://opteo.com/dev/google-ads-api

Comment: Great Thanks man,
I wish you answered this a year ago ^_^,
However your answer still worth it, thanks

Comment: Maybe it didn't exist a year ago! Hehe. Can this answer still be accepted this answer?

Answer (score 2):

AdWords looks like not supporting Node.JS API call for now. But you can find all the documentation here : https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start

The library you mentioned seems to be good as 3k developers download it weekly.